# How to uniquely flag duplicate rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, distinct, flags

I want to try to uniquely flag the a dataset (df) based on duplicate observations on certain rows. As an example:

```
 ID      Name1     Name2      Name3     Name4    Name5
   1       abc       NA         rr       def      NA
   2       AA        NA         NA       NA       NA
   3       abc       NA         rr       def      NA
   5       rty       NA         NA       NA       NA
   6       rty       NA         NA       NA       NA
   7       rty       NA         NA       NA       NA
```

but I want a dataset that flags the identical rows based on names 1 through 5  and removes unique rows as follows

```r
 ID      Name1     Name2      Name3     Name4    Name5    Flag
   1       abc       NA         rr       def      NA       a
   3       abc       NA         rr       def      NA       a
   5       rty       NA         NA       NA       NA       b
   6       rty       NA         NA       NA       NA       b
   7       rty       NA         NA       NA       NA       b
```

So far I have done this:

```r
duplicated(df[c(-1)])|duplicated(df[c(-1)]
```

but this only does not flag the duplicate columns.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach using base R, where we (1) filter unique duplicate rows (without taking into account `ID`) with `duplicated` and `unique` adding an additional `Flag` column, and (2) merge the filtered data.frame back to the original on the `Name` columns:

```r
df1 <- unique(df[duplicated(df[, -1]) | duplicated(df[, -1], fromLast = TRUE), -1])
df1$Flag <- letters[seq_len(nrow(df1))]

merge(df, df1, by = names(df)[-1])

#>   Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 ID Flag
#> 1   abc    NA    rr   def    NA  1    a
#> 2   abc    NA    rr   def    NA  3    a
#> 3   rty    NA  <NA>  <NA>    NA  5    b
#> 4   rty    NA  <NA>  <NA>    NA  6    b
#> 5   rty    NA  <NA>  <NA>    NA  7    b
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Name1 = c("abc", 
            "AA", "abc", "rty", "rty", "rty"), Name2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
            NA, NA), Name3 = c("rr", NA, "rr", NA, NA, NA), Name4 = c("def", 
            NA, "def", NA, NA, NA), Name5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
        -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  group_by_at(vars(starts_with("Name"))) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  mutate(Flag = group_indices()) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 7
     ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5  Flag
  <int> <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <int>
1     1 abc   NA    rr    def   NA        1
2     3 abc   NA    rr    def   NA        1
3     5 rty   NA    <NA>  <NA>  NA        2
4     6 rty   NA    <NA>  <NA>  NA        2
5     7 rty   NA    <NA>  <NA>  NA        2
```

Comment: I like this answer too, but what if the variables all didn't start with name? Can I just do:
group_by_at(vars( c(whatever variables i want here)))??